# How can I change HubControl orientation using the VisualStateManager?

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, visualstatemanager

When I change the Orientation property of a HubControl using the VisualStateManager in my Windows 8.1 app, the app crashes with an unhandled Win32 exception.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
      <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Hub" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Orientation">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Horizontal"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
      <Storyboard>
         <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Hub" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Orientation">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Vertical"/>
         </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
  </VisualStateGroup>
```

When I change other properties of the HubControl, such as its Visibility, it works like I would expect. Am I doing something wrong or is there a reason why the Orientation property can't be set this way?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Nope. I eventually gave up and solved it in the code-behind.